# Erasing cells that want to reappear

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I'm writing a game called [**Chomp**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomp), I've completed the game itself, but I'm having some visual bugs that I am having trouble fixing. Whenever you click on a square in this game (except for the green square), certain squares including the clicked square supposed to fade and disappear forever.

Currently, however, when the user clicks a square it creates a after-image of the whole table. For example, [**this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcAc3.jpg) is how a piece looks after clicking the center square as a first move, and as you can see in my second move [**here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BjrG.jpg) the pieces in the first move reappear briefly, only to soon fade out again.

Whenever squares are erased, they should never re-appear as they are currently, I'm not sure what's causing this behavior. But I believe it may be due to the html elements not being deleted properly. How can I make the squares that have faded not show up again?

Here is my html for *gameTable*

```
    <!--game table-->
<table id="gameTable"> 
</table>
```

and my javascript functions for handling cell clicks, and fading elements

```
   fadeOut = function fadeOut(state) {
      // Make fadeOut unavailable until the whole fade-out is finished.
      fadeOut.isAvailableToRun = false;
      // Update the distance moved and apply it to the element.
      state.distance += state.distanceIncrement;
      state.element.style.top = state.distance + 'px'; //move up by pixels
      // Update the opacity and apply it to the element.
      state.opacity += state.opacityIncrement;
      state.element.style.opacity = state.opacity;
      //if opacity is > 0 , fade it out into the ethers
      if (state.opacity > 0) {
         // If the element is still showing, wait a bit and then continue fading it.
         setTimeout(function () {
            fadeOut(state);
         }, state.timeIncrement);
      }
   };

   //contains values to use for fadeOut
   cellClick = function (cell) {
      var a, x, y;

      //make all cells above, to the right, and inbetween fade a clicked cell fade
      for (a = 0; a < tableData.length; a += 1) {
         //get x,y coordinates from tableData
         x = cell.pos.x;
         y = cell.pos.y;
         //erase position in index compared to the clicked position
         if (tableData[a].pos.x <= x && tableData[a].pos.y >= y) {
            //remove clickability of cells other than clicked cell
            tableData[a].onclick = null;
            //apply fadeOut effect to cells other than clicked cell
            fadeOut({
               distance: 0, // initial distance from start
               distanceIncrement: 1, // number of pixels to move each timer tick
               element: tableData[a], // element to move and fade (cell, element passed as a parameter to the click cell function)
               opacity: 1, // initial opacity
               opacityIncrement: -0.01, // how much to fade each timer tick
               pause: 1000, // milliseconds to pause after completed fade
               timeIncrement: 10 // milliseconds for each timer tick
            });
         }
      }
```

[**Here**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpQPKj) is my code in it's entirety, with a live demo so you can easily see the problem for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you're telling all the cells in the region to fade out again, even if they've faded out already. I changed your code to now check if a cell's `opacity` CSS property has been set. If the opacity is already set, then the cell is already faded, and we avoid calling `fadeOut` again. Otherwise, we continue with calling the method. This seemed to fix your issue.

[Here's a link to my fork of your code.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZwVqB)

Comment: Thanks, I did a similar solution from the suggestion of Padge, but yours is cleaner. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using  `state.opacity += state.opacityIncrement;`. This will take the initial state of the opacity you pass in (1), and then decrement it correctly. Even if the square is invisible, you make the first iteration start at essentially `1 - 0.01`.

Instead of hardcoding this to 1, you should get the opacity of the existing square.